# In ASP.NET page is redirecting to the empty page or server can't display the page after updating record in datagridview

Tags: asp.net

After updating the record in the datagridview i had redirected it to the same page using server.redirect. But its remaining on the same page and showing the error 'server cannot display the page'. But the record is updating in the database. and if I copy the url and paste it in the other instance of the browser the datagridview shows the record with updated values. When I run the solution on local machine its working fine but after posting on the dev server the above error is coming.
Please, suggest any solution on this.
Thank you.

Comment: Please show us code and exception stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using server.redirect?  If it's the same page, just complete the operations and allow it to post back.

Regarding why it's crashing, please post code...although simply using post back will probably fix the issue.